# How to create a hook in React that works like this.setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to create a hook that works like this.setState but I don't know how to implement functionality that works like callback in this.setState. Do you have any ideas?

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const useSetState = (initialState) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState)
  const setPartialState = (stateToSet, callback) => {
    console.log('stateToSet: ', stateToSet);
    console.log('callback: ', callback);
    if (typeof stateToSet === 'function') {
      setPartialState(stateToSet(state));
    } else if (typeof state === 'object' &&
      typeof stateToSet === 'object' &&
      !Array.isArray(state) &&
      !Array.isArray(stateToSet)
    ) {
      setState({ ...state, ...stateToSet });
    } else {
      setState(stateToSet);
    }
  }
  return [state, setPartialState]
}


const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useSetState(0);
  const checkCount = () => {
    if (count === 10) {
      console.log('Booooom!');
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Counter: {count}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCount((count + 1, checkCount))}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What kind of behavior would like to have ? I don't understand much what you try to achieve in your function setPartialState and why you try to manipulate array at some points.

Answer (score 0):

While working with React hooks, you need to use different mindset as compare to when using the class based React components.

If you want to do something when the count is changed to 10, you should do it inside the useEffect hook.

```
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (count === 10) {
      console.log('Booooom!');
    }
  }, [count])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Counter: {count}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```